# css transform rotate not working

Tags: html, css

Sorry guys I have here a big code section but this is for detailing the code I have done , but the issue is very small one related to HTML and CSS. 
Here I used an arrow ◢ as content in a class called .bulletInline:before but some browser doesn't show the rotated arrow in second column. Please help me to resolve this issue. **css transform rotate is not working in some browsers**

```js
function LoadCreditText(idcredit)
{
document.getElementById("idiv_"+idcredit).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("crd_"+idcredit).style.display="";

}
function DisableCreditText(idcredits)
{
document.getElementById("idiv_"+idcredits).style.display="";
document.getElementById("crd_"+idcredits).style.display="none";

}

set_flag=1;
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}
function stateChanged()
{//alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{

 if(set_flag==1) 
 {
document.getElementById("set_1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
evalScript(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("set_1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("set_2").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("set_3").style.display="none";
   }
   if(set_flag==2) 
 {
document.getElementById("set_2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
evalScript(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("set_2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("set_1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("set_3").style.display="none";
   }
  if(set_flag==3) 
 {
 
 //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
 
document.getElementById("set_3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
evalScript(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("set_3").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("set_2").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("set_1").style.display="none";



   }
   document.getElementById("loading").style.display="none";
  
}
}

function paging(set)
{


if(document.getElementById("set_"+set).innerHTML !="")
{
//alert(set);
 if(set==1) 
  {
                  //alert(set);
 document.getElementById("set_1").style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("set_2").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("set_3").style.display="none";

    }

    if(set==2) 
  {
                //alert(set);
 document.getElementById("set_2").style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("set_1").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("set_3").style.display="none";
 
    }
   
    if(set==3) 
  {
        
 document.getElementById("set_3").style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("set_2").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("set_1").style.display="none";
         }
               
    return;
}


document.getElementById("set_"+set_flag).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("loading").style.display="block";
set_flag=set;

xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }

var url="http://appldp.com/publisher-show-ads-paging.php?"+"set="+set+"&id=353&ht=150&hostname=adserver.tistory.com&r=f&blockcount=9&content_type=utf-8&search=&title=%EA%B3%A0%EC%9F%81%EC%9D%B4%7E%7E%7E%20%3A%3A%20%EA%B4%91%EA%B3%A0%EC%9F%81%EC%9D%B4%7E%7E%7E&desc=&ref=&searchmetat=%EA%B4%91%EA%B3%A0%EC%9F%81%EC%9D%B4%7E%7E%7E&searchmetatdes=&server_path_id=1&original_url_string=http%3A%2F%2Fappldp.com%2F";








//alert(url);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",encodeURI(url),true);
xmlhttp.send(null);




}



function evalScript(scripts)
{ 
try
 { if(scripts != '') 
  { var script = "";
   scripts = scripts.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
                                  if (scripts !== null) script += arguments[1] + '\n';
                                   return '';});
   
   //alert(script);
   if(script) (window.execScript) ? window.execScript(script) : window.setTimeout(script, 0);
  }
  return false;
 }
 catch(e)
 { alert(e)
 }
}
 


<!-- vins[SHORTEN_TEXT]  -->


var i;
var j;
var numberOfTitleChar = '35';
var numberOfDescChar = '50';
var textAdCombination = '0';

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var descriptionDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

if(numberOfTitleChar==''){
 numberOfTitleChar='35';
}

if(numberOfDescChar==''){
 numberOfDescChar='50';
}

for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
  if(links[i].className == 'titleLink') {
   links[i].innerHTML = links[i].innerHTML.substring(0,numberOfTitleChar);
  }
}

for(j=0;j<descriptionDivs.length;j++) {
  if(descriptionDivs[j].className == 'inout-desc') {
   descriptionDivs[j].innerHTML = descriptionDivs[j].innerHTML.substring(0,numberOfDescChar);
  }
}

if(textAdCombination=='1'){
 for(j=0;j<descriptionDivs.length;j++) {
   if(descriptionDivs[j].className == 'inout-desc') {
    descriptionDivs[j].style.display="none";
   }
 }
}else if(textAdCombination=='2'){
 for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
   if(links[i].className == 'titleLink') {
    links[i].style.display="none";
   }
 }
}
```

```css
.top, .bottom {display:block; background:transparent; font-size:1px;width:575;}
.tb1, .tb2, .tb3, .tb4 {display:block; overflow:hidden;}
.tb1, .tb2, .tb3 {height:1px;}
.tb2, .tb3, .tb4 {


background:#FFFFFF; border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF; border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
.tb1 {margin:0 5px;  background:#FFFFFF;  }
.tb2 {margin:0 3px; border-width:0 2px;}
.tb3 {margin:0 2px;}
.tb4 {
 height:2px;

 margin:0 1px;}
.bb1, .bb2, .bb3, .bb4 {display:block; overflow:hidden;}
.bb1, .bb2, .bb3 {height:1px;}
.bb2, .bb3, .bb4 {background:#FFFFFF; border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF; border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
.bb1 {margin:0 5px; background:#FFFFFF;}
.bb2 {margin:0 3px; border-width:0 2px;}
.bb3 {margin:0 2px;}
.bb4 {height:2px; margin:0 1px;}
.parenttable {display:block; background:#FFFFFF; border-style:solid; border-color: #FFFFFF; border-width:0 1px; padding: 0px;margin:0 0px;}


body{

padding:0;
margin:0;
style=background-color:transparent;
}
.inout-table{

 border: 1px solid  #FFFFFF;
 background:#FFFFFF;
padding:0px 0px;
margin:0px 0px;
table-layout:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
line-height: 7px;



}

/* vins[TEXT_AD_STYLE] */
 .inout-desc 
 {
  overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: justify;
 }
 .inout-title{
  overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: justify;
 }
 

.inout-desc , .inout-title
{
}

.topWrapper{
 display: none;
}
.topWrapper{
 display: block;
 height:0px;
}
.adHeading{
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  float: left;
 margin-left: 5px;
   color:#0080C9;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:14px;
   font-weight:bold;
   }
dl.textAdTitles {
/*$totalAdCounts*/
 columns: 1;
 -webkit-columns: 1;
 -moz-columns: 1;
 columns: 2;
 -webkit-columns: 2;
 -moz-columns: 2;
 -webkit-column-gap: 5px; 
 -moz-column-gap: 5px; 
 column-gap: 5px;

 list-style-position: inside;
 margin-left:5px; 
 margin-right:20px;
 width: 575px; 
}

dt{
 /*margin-top: 5px;*/
 line-height:1.5em;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.textAdTitles {
 counter-reset: my-badass-counter;
}
.bulletInline:before {
 font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 width:12px;
 height:auto;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: 0px;
 display: inline-block;

 font-size: 10px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color:#000000; /*$textAdTitleBulletColor*/ 
 font-weight: bolder;
 /*content: ' ▶';
 transform: scale(0.5,1);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.5,1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,1);*/

 content: '◢';
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }


.adCustomHead{
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
 font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 color:#000000;
 float: right;
 }
/* vins[END] */
/* vins[TEXT_AD_STYLING] */
 .inout-table
 {
  border-color: FFFFFF;
 }
    .inout-table
   {
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
   }
  
.inout-table
{
 }
/* vins[END] */


.inout-table td
{
}
.marqueetable
{
padding:0 0;
margin:0 0;
table-layout:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
line-height: 7px;
}

  .inout-title a:link,.inout-title a:visited,.inout-title a:hover,.inout-title a:active,.inout-title a:focus
  {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12;
  /*color:;*/
  margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
  padding:0px;
  /* vins[TEXT_AD_STYLE] */
      color:#363636;

  

  /* vins[END] */
  }
  
  
  .inout-desc 
  {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12;
  color:#0F0F0F;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
  padding:0px;
    }
  
  
  .inout-url a:link,.inout-url a:visited,.inout-url a:hover,.inout-url a:active,.inout-url a:focus
  {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:14;
  color:#009933;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
   white-space:nowrap;
  padding:0px;
  }


.inout_credit_over
{
font-size:12px;
height:15px;
/*background-image:url(images/tabs.png);*/
background-color:#FFFFFF;
background-repeat:repeat;
color:#000000;

position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;


}
.inout_credit_data
{
overflow:hidden;
max-width:575px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;

}










.inout-credit
{

height:15px;
width:auto;
background-color:#FFFFFF;


/*padding-left:0px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-top:0px;*/




white-space:nowrap;
text-align:right;
/* vins[TEXT_AD_STYLE] */
 
height:25px;
padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
/* vins[END] */

}

/* vins[TEXT_AD_STYLE] */
  .inout-credit
  {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
 
   .inout-credit
  {
   border-bottom-style:solid;
   border-bottom-width:0.1em;
   border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
/* vins[END] */


.inout-credit-next a:link
{
height:15px;
/*background-color:#FFFFFF;
padding:0 5;*/
background-color:none;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
color:#000000;
/*border:1px solid red;*/
width:auto;


padding-right:0px;



text-align:left;
float:left;
color:#000000;
margin-top: -3px;


}
#cred
{


float:right;


width:515px;
 
width:100%; /* vins[TEXT_AD_STYLE] */

overflow:hidden;

}

#nex 
{
color:;
color:#000000;
font-size:22px;
font-family:serif;
background-color:;
background-color:none;
padding:0 3px;

}
#nex1 
{
color:;
color:#000000;
font-size:22px;
font-family:serif;
background-color:;
background-color:none;
padding:0 3px;


}
#nex2 
{
color:;
color:#000000;
font-size:22px;
font-family:serif;
background-color:;
background-color:none;

padding:0 3px;

}





/*
.inout-credit-next a:link,.inout-credit-next a:visited,.inout-credit-next a:hover,.inout-credit-next a:active,.inout-credit-next a:focus
{

font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


font-weight:normal;

text-decoration:none;


}
*/
.inout-credit a:link,.inout-credit a:visited,.inout-credit a:hover,.inout-credit a:active,.inout-credit a:focus
{
color:#000000;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height: 15px;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#000000;
 

}
```

```html
<div id="set_1" style="width:575"><table height="150" width="575" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="inout-table"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-left:5px" class="inout-credit"><div id="cred"><a class="adCustomHead" target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/index.php?r=6">AD</a><span class="inout-credit-next" style="display:none"><a style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000" id="nex" href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="paging(2);return true">»</a></span><span class="adHeading">[핫클릭 이슈]</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="topWrapper"></td></tr><tr><td class="inoutADS"><dl class="textAdTitles"><dt height="0" style="display: none;"><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title alignmenty"><a style="font-weight:bolder;" target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3404&amp;kid=24611&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc">[재무설계] 노후준비 천천히? 미루다 때 놓쳐…재테크도 결국 '</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3404&amp;kid=24611&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a style="font-weight:bolder;" target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3404&amp;kid=24611&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=9066f42b1099ce9dee407bbf09b0f57a">[재무설계] 노후준비 천천히? 미루다 때 놓쳐…재테크도 결국 '</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3404&amp;kid=24611&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=9066f42b1099ce9dee407bbf09b0f57a"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3405&amp;kid=24621&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=682469e3ed63df401224beaaf7b5bcd3">설연휴 ‘먹방’에 불어난 살 없애는 스마트한 다이어트 주목</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3405&amp;kid=24621&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=682469e3ed63df401224beaaf7b5bcd3"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3406&amp;kid=24629&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=44eab20b0768d7ec756dca1d31b389db">스트레스 받는 하체비만, “다이어트로 허벅지살 쉽게 빼자”</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3406&amp;kid=24629&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=44eab20b0768d7ec756dca1d31b389db"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3407&amp;kid=24646&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=79038299b630a7de4776c4cb71c88eb5">'뱃살, 허벅지살' 2주만에 '확' 빼는 단기간 다이어트 방법</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3407&amp;kid=24646&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=79038299b630a7de4776c4cb71c88eb5"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3408&amp;kid=24647&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=32a6549e99c9a2b876a7d8e511e96869">갑자기 찐 5kg, 피할 수 없는 나잇살 다이어트 방법은?</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3408&amp;kid=24647&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=32a6549e99c9a2b876a7d8e511e96869"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3409&amp;kid=24663&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=c3c2724f557bcb58af055537c0996df7">[쌈짓돈 재테크] 나는 이렇게 벌었다</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3409&amp;kid=24663&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=c3c2724f557bcb58af055537c0996df7"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3411&amp;kid=24684&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=ad82c0a0eec00c178080ed0c7144f648">웨딩시즌, 웨딩페어…봄보다 먼저 온 예비부부 모셔요</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3411&amp;kid=24684&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=ad82c0a0eec00c178080ed0c7144f648"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3412&amp;kid=24694&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=6c1595d6a610d964b31b4127effb9ee8">웨딩 전문가 맞춤 컨설팅 결혼준비, 어렵지 않아요</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3412&amp;kid=24694&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=6c1595d6a610d964b31b4127effb9ee8"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3413&amp;kid=24701&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=2dd223709b045ad79d3e6d8edb0a5ee3">소비자가 필요한 금융정보 모두 모은 포털사이트 생긴다</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3413&amp;kid=24701&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=2dd223709b045ad79d3e6d8edb0a5ee3"></a></div></dt><dt height="" style=""><span class="bulletInline"></span><span class="inout-title  alignmentx"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3414&amp;kid=24714&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=9ed6af4d35cbf33f414725e6e1b9b8c3">법인컨설팅, 중소기업의 경영안정성을 높이다</a></span><div class="inout-desc"></div><div class="inout-url"><a target="_blank" href="http://appldp.com/ppc-publisher-ad-click.php?id=3414&amp;kid=24714&amp;pid=6&amp;bid=353&amp;vid=3667&amp;vip=f9dedd0ff611d85fc169b73a6602d6fb&amp;direct_status=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b&amp;bs=9ed6af4d35cbf33f414725e6e1b9b8c3"></a></div></dt></dl></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: That seems to be working fine with Chrome, Firefox and Edge! Which browser you are facing issue on?

Comment: Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111

Comment: Why does it have 10 items (5x2)  in 2-column view, but in a single column it's only 7? I can't read it so I can't tell what's being split.

Comment: Yes...It supports Chrome version 49 and above caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: @SaurabhSharma click "show all" - chrome 47 supports transform.